# Track ERC20 Provenance

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I was wondering if there is any way for a smart contract to determine where a specific ERC20 transfer came from. That's to say:

Alice and Bob both send a transfer to a smart contract same amount & token and both tx mined on the same block.

Can the smart contract given the SC address of the ERC20 token and the amount determine who sent it, some how?

I know you can determine if the SC owns the fund by doing smth like this:

```
function sendTokens(address _tokenContract, uint _amountContributed){
      if(uniqueSwap._tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))!=_amountContributed){revert();}
    }
```

Im after a bit more trace-ability than this though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You usually use `allow()` and `transferFrom()` to accomplish this.

Comment: If u can give some context and links in an answer ill happilly mark it as correct